# Why in the quran Allah use the you ( singular) and sometimes you

Tags: quran, tafseer

I dont understand what s the difference between two

why Allah use sometimes the plural form and sometimes the sinular form

anyone knows maybe the singular form is a way of communicate more closely  I dont know...

Comment: [This](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/900/why-some-verses-of-quran-refer-to-god-as-a-plural-entity?rq=1) should cover your inquiry. If not please add examples to make clear what you mean.

Comment: It hard to make example since in English there is no différence between you when I talk to a single person or you when I talk to many  like in Arabic, the quran use both I don't understand why sometimes Allah use the plural form and other times the singular form of you when he ask us to do  something

Comment: Do you mean why Allah sometimes uses "We" and sometimes uses "I"?

Answer (score 1):

Singular form almost always refers to the Prophet Muhammad (SAW). For example:

> And who believe in what has been revealed to **you**, [O Muhammad], and what was revealed before you, and of the Hereafter they are certain [in faith]. (2:4)

Sometimes it may be singular outwardly referring to the Prophet Muhammad (SAW), but refer to Muslims or people in general by extension through the Prophet. It is simply a way of speaking. For example:

> The truth is from **your** Lord, so **do not be** among the doubters. (3:60)

The message is for people in general (since the Prophet does not doubt) but it is said in proxy through the Prophet (SAW).

Plural form can refer to different groups of people including but not limited to Muslims, Bani Israel, and all humans in general depending on context.

> **Muslims**: "Neither those who disbelieve from the People of the Scripture nor the polytheists wish that any good should be sent down to **you** from your Lord. But Allah selects for His mercy whom He wills, and Allah is the possessor of great bounty." (2:105)

> **Bani Israel**: "O Children of Israel, remember My favor which I have bestowed upon **you** and fulfill My covenant [upon you] that I will fulfill **your** covenant [from Me], and be afraid of [only] Me." (2:40)

> **Mankind**: "O mankind, worship your Lord, who created **you** and those before **you**, that you may become righteous" (2:21)